Understanding the Absence of Odd-sided Shapes in Dirichlet Domains: Theorems and Discussion
I am studying the shape of dirichlet domains.
I understood that the following Theorem 10.5.1 of Beardon provides the bounds on the number of sides. And the Umemoto's paper (See References) also discusses the case of triangle groups. But, I was not quite convinced why a shape with odd number of sides doesn't appear. Any suggestion or help is highly appreciated.
Theorem 10.5.1 of Beardon
Let $I$ be a cofinite Fuchsian group with signature $(g; m_1, \dots, m_n)$, and let $D_p(T)$ be the Dirichlet polygon with center $p$ with $N$ sides. Then

$N \leq 12g + 4n - 6,$
If $n = 0$, then $N \geq 4g,$
If $n \geq 1$, then $N \geq 4g + 2n - 2.$

References

Beardon, Alan F. The geometry of discrete groups. Vol. 91. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.
Umemoto, Yuriko. On Dirichlet fundamental domains for Fuchsian groups. Diss. Master Thesis, Graduate School of Science, Osaka City University, 2011.


Where does it say that the number of sides has to be even? Also, do you allow reflections and what exactly do you mean by a side? (The latter is a tricky issue because of fixed points of involutions.)

For instance, at the bottom of Page 30, Umemoto says that possible number of sides are 4 or 6 and goes on to Theorem 24 considering only those two.
By sides, I meant the side of a dirichlet domain.

You should structure your question so that one does not have to read that paper in order to understand the question. Presumably Umemoto's theorems have some assumptions since in general the quoted claims are obviously false.

@MoisheKohan I see. can you provide any reference showing the claim being false?

Just look at part 3 of the theorem from Bredon's book that you quoted and use large $g$ or $n$.

First of all, the number of sides of a Dirichlet fundamental polygon can be infinite. Let's assume that this is not the case (i.e. the discrete group of isometries of the hyperbolic plane is finitely generated). To get a simple example of a Dirichlet polygon with odd number of sides, take a subgroup $\Gamma$ of $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ of order 2 generated by a single involution $\tau$, for instance, $\tau(z)=-1/z$. Let $q$ denote the unique fixed point of $\tau$ in the hyperbolic plane. Take a point $p\in \mathbb H^2$ not fixed by $\tau$. Then the corresponding Dirichlet domain $D(\Gamma, p)$ has exactly one side, the geodesic $c\subset \mathbb H^2$ passing through $q$ and bisecting the geodesic $p\tau(p)$.
On the other hand, suppose that $\Gamma< PSL(2, \mathbb R)$ is a discrete finitely generated subgroup which contains no involutions. Then for every side $s\subset \partial D(\Gamma, p)$ is contained in a bisector of $p \gamma(p)$ ($\gamma\in \Gamma\setminus \{1\}$), the bisector of $p \gamma^{-1}(p)$ also contributes a side $s'$ to the domain $D(\Gamma, p)$. Since $\gamma^2\ne 1$, it follows that $s\ne s'$. Hence, all sides are paired and, hence, there is even number of sides. The same argument works for general fundamental polygons (not necessarily Dirichlet domains).
